# Possible Layoff on National D 18b(2) Visa's Fiktion Certificate. What to do?

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card, residency

"I was issued a national D visa under Section 18b (2) of the Residence Act (AufenthG) in August to work in Germany. This visa expired in February, and I was issued a fiktion certificate in March. Now, I've heard rumors about potential layoffs in my company in the coming week. I have a notice period of three months.

During this notice period, am I allowed to look for another job? And after my notice period ends, can I legally work for a different company even though my visa has the name of my current employer on it? What steps should I take to maintain legal residence in Germany?

Additionally, considering my situation, would I be eligible for unemployment benefits? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How long have you had the 18b visa? Or is it 18c(2)?

Comment: unemployment benefits is an insurance, so it will depend how long you have been working. [Arbeitslosengeld: Anspruch, Höhe, Dauer | Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/arbeitslos-arbeit-finden/arbeitslosengeld/finanzielle-hilfen/arbeitslosengeld-anspruch-hoehe-dauer): *In order to be entitled to unemployment benefit, you must meet the **qualifying period**. This is the case if you were compulsorily or voluntarily insured in the unemployment insurance scheme **for at least 12 months in the 30 months** before you registered as unemployed and became unemployed.*

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment:

> During this notice period, am I allowed to look for another job?

You are not only allowed, but you have *the right* to look for another job in your notice period. Inside normal, reasonable limits your employer cannot hinder you to take time off for interviews and other activities for job search. While you still have to take PTO if you want to be paid during that time, you can also take unpaid leave without repercussions.

Be sure to communicate clearly and early that your leave is for those reasons, it might reflect poorly on you if you just disappear without explanation.

Comment: This covers the job seeking. I expect the OP worries about the residence permit.